# Unix Shell Script displaying null in a text file when open in wordpad

Tags: shell, unix

Does anyone know how to convert Hex(00) to display Null in wordpad using Unix Shell Scripting.

I have an output file which is a text file and through unix I need to convert a hex value 00 to display like a box (null) in Word pad on a particular line.

Currently by using the following code I am not getting anything in my output file:

hexchar="00"
octchar=$(echo "ibase=16;obase=8;$hexchar"|bc)
hex1=$(echo "\0$octchar")

Please help!!!

Comment: ok, so can you tell us what's your actual problem? why do you need to do that?

Comment: Are you working on Cygwin to get Wordpad and the Unix shell together?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one reference that might be useful.

[**Need to grep for null Characters in an acsii file.**](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1249450&page=13)

---

The following will remove all the null characters,

```
tr -d "\000" < input.txt > output.txt
```

And, this will replace it with the `X` character -- take your pick,

```
tr "\000" "X" < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will not run. This test proves it: if you open an empty wordpad, enter only that one character: 1 (one). Then (then) press Alt+x and you will see that box. You can type hex numbers until utf-16 (or so), but if you enter a 0 instead of the 1, you will get 30, the ansi value of 0. Maybe that hex 0 was avoided because of any ambiguity in the os file system  or so. But hex 0 can not be displayed (even not as a box).